# Python print function issues

Tags: python, string, function, printing, formatting

I'm new to Python and am working with Python 3.3.2..  I'm having trouble including data items in strings that I am trying to print.  The `%` operator either prints out literally as in:

```
for miles in range (10, 70, 10):
    km=miles*1.609
    print ("%d miles --> %3.2f kilometers") % (miles, km)
```

produces:

```
%d miles --> %3.2f kilometers
```

along with the error:

```
Unsupported operand type for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'
```

But when I change the third line to:

```
print (%d "miles -->" %3.2f "kilometers") % (miles, km)
```

I get a syntax error on the %d.  I was able to get the program to work correctly from the interactive mode by eliminating the '`print()`' function but it will not produce an output in IDLE without the '`print()`'.  What am I missing?  The research I have done trying to figure this out has been helpful in learning more about Python, but so far hasn't gotten the program working.  By the way it should output:

```
10 miles --> 16.09 kilometers
20 miles --> 32.18 kilometers
30 miles --> 48.27 kilometers
40 miles --> 64.36 kilometers
50 miles --> 80.45 kilometers
60 miles --> 96.54 kilometers
```

I appreciate any help or assistance I can get on this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `% (miles, km)` inside the `print` function:

`print` function returns `None`, so in your code you're actually trying to do:

```
None % (miles, km)
```

That's why you're getting that error.

**Working code:**

```
>>> for miles in range (10, 70, 10):
...      km=miles*1.609
...      print ("%d miles --> %3.2f kilometers" % (miles, km))
...     
10 miles --> 16.09 kilometers
20 miles --> 32.18 kilometers
30 miles --> 48.27 kilometers
40 miles --> 64.36 kilometers
50 miles --> 80.45 kilometers
60 miles --> 96.54 kilometers
```

Using **new style [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec)**:

```
>>> for miles in range (10, 70, 10):
        km=miles*1.609
        print ("{:d} miles --> {:3.2f} kilometers".format(miles, km))
...     
10 miles --> 16.09 kilometers
20 miles --> 32.18 kilometers
30 miles --> 48.27 kilometers
40 miles --> 64.36 kilometers
50 miles --> 80.45 kilometers
60 miles --> 96.54 kilometers
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Knew it had to be something simple.  Got it working now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Try using .format() method on your sting

```
>>> for miles in range(10, 70, 10):
...     km = miles*1.609
...     print ("{0} miles ---> {1} kilometers".format(miles, km))
```

Answer (score 2):

You've already got an answer as to why your print isn't working - however, a slightly different way of writing this is:

```
miles = range(10, 70, 10)
kms = (m * 1.609 for m in miles)
fmt = '{:d} miles --> {:3.2f} kilometers'.format
print(*map(fmt, miles, kms), sep='\n')
```

Gives:

```
10 miles --> 16.09 kilometers
20 miles --> 32.18 kilometers
30 miles --> 48.27 kilometers
40 miles --> 64.36 kilometers
50 miles --> 80.45 kilometers
60 miles --> 96.54 kilometers
```